# Swipecards - how to get current card index?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use the Swipecards example from here: https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards/blob/master/README.md

I have the Swipecards working, however, I am trying to get the index of the current card that was swiped right. When a card is swiped right onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) is called and I want to have the index of the card that was swiped at this point.

How can I get this index/position of the card?

I tried using the dataObject parameter but that just contains the contents of that card and not its position.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

### EDIT:

Figured it out, the when you swipe left or right the element is removed from the arraylist so the element you are currently looking at is always at position 0.

Answer (score 0):

Since the cards are stored in `ArrayList al` you can use `al.indexOf(dataObject)` to get the index of an object.

Comment: I dont think that would work, it always returns -1 for the index of the dataObject even though the data object does have the correct card's information in it.

Comment: Try to cast dataObject to String: `al.indexOf((String) dataObject)`